# How to get Numbers from the method consecutively?

Tags: javascript

I am making javascript *calculator program without using eval()* function. The problem that I had is I click the menu from button let's say 7. I save it in the `num1`, later I clear input screen and I again I want to  get input and save it in `num2` according to operation I want to show the result to User but I can't save the second number and show it I don't where the problem is. I am struggling since morning any help is appreciated Thanks a lot.

```js
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
var check = true;
var flag = true;
var memory = 0;

function getValue(par) {
  document.getElementById("input").value = par.toString();
  num1 = par;
  if (flag == true) {
    num1 = parseInt(par);
    flag = false;
  } else {
    num2 = parseInt(par);
    flag = true;
  }
  if (par == "C") {
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;
  }
}

function getOperator(val) {
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";

  if (val == "topla") {
    memory = num1 + num2;
  } else if (value = "=") {
    document.getElementById("input").value = memory;
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 280px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#numbers {
  width: 210px;
  height: 310px;
  float: left;
}
#numbers button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
#operators {
  margin-top: 1px;
  float: right;
  width: 70px;
  height: 310px;
}
#operators button {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="input1">
    <input id="input">
  </div>
  <div id="numbers">
    <button type="button" value="9" onclick="getValue('9')">9</button>
    <button type="button" value="8" onclick="getValue('8')">8</button>
    <button type="button" value="7" onclick="getValue('7')">7</button>
    <button type="button" value="6" onclick="getValue('6')">6</button>
    <button type="button" value="5" onclick="getValue('5')">5</button>
    <button type="button" value="4" onclick="getValue('4')">4</button>
    <button type="button" value="3" onclick="getValue('3')">3</button>
    <button type="button" value="2" onclick="getValue('2')">2</button>
    <button type="button" value="1" onclick="getValue('1')">1</button>
    <button type="button" value="0" onclick="getValue('0')">0</button>
    <button type="button" value="=" onclick="getOperator('=')">=</button>
    <button type="button" value="C" onclick="getV*emphasized text*alue('C')">C</button>
  </div>
  <div id="operators">
    <button type="button" value="topla" onclick="getOperator('topla')">+</button>
    <button type="button" value="cıkar" onclick="getOperator('cıkar')">-</button>
    <button type="button" value="bol" onclick="getOperator('carp')">/</button>
    <button type="button" value="carp" onclick="getOperator('bol')">*</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.`memory= parseInt(num1 )+parseInt(num2);` add addition like this.This is only add with two numbers.

2. see the second term you are wrongly declare `value` instead of `val`

**So change `if(val == "="){`  instead of `if(value  ="="){`**

```js
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
var check = true;
var flag = true;
var memory = 0;

function getValue(par) {
   document.getElementById("input").value=par.toString();
    num1=par;
   if(flag) {
    num1=parseInt(par);
    flag=false;
   }else{   
   num2=parseInt(par);
     console.log(num2)
   flag=false;
   }
    if(par =="C"){
      document.getElementById("input").value="";
        num1=0;
        num2=0;
        
    }
        
}

function getOperator(val){
     document.getElementById("input").value="";
    
    if(val =="topla"){    
        memory= parseInt(num1 )+parseInt(num2);
   
    }else if(val  =="="){
        
        document.getElementById("input").value=memory;
    }
  
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
    width:280px;
    height:350px;
    border:5px solid gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
    
}

#numbers{
    
    width:210px;
    height:310px;
    float:left;
}
#numbers button {
    float:left;
    
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    margin:5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}

#operators {
    margin-top:1px;
    
    float:right;
    width:70px;
    height:310px;
}

#operators button{
     
    display:block;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width:60px;
    height:60px;
    margin-top:8px; 
    margin-left:2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:white;
   background-color:red;
    font-size: 25px;
    
}
#input {
    margin-top:5px;
    border:5px solid gray;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:270px;
    height:50px;
    
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Calculator</title>
        <link href="calculator.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="calculator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    
    <div  id="wrapper">
        <div class="input1">
        <input id="input" >
         </div>
        
        <div id="numbers">
             
            <button type="button" value="9" onclick="getValue('9')">9</button>
            <button type="button" value="8" onclick="getValue('8')" >8</button>
            <button type="button" value="7" onclick="getValue('7')">7</button>
            <button type="button" value="6" onclick="getValue('6')">6</button>
            <button type="button" value="5" onclick="getValue('5')">5</button>
            <button type="button" value="4" onclick="getValue('4')">4</button>
            <button type="button" value="3" onclick="getValue('3')">3</button>
            <button type="button" value="2" onclick="getValue('2')">2</button>
            <button type="button" value="1" onclick="getValue('1')">1</button>
            <button type="button" value="0" onclick="getValue('0')">0</button>
            <button type="button" value="=" onclick="getOperator('=')">=</button>
            <button type="button" value="C" onclick="getValue('C')">C</button>
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="operators">
            <button type="button" value="topla" onclick="getOperator('topla')" >+</button>
            <button type="button" value="cıkar" onclick="getOperator('cıkar')" >-</button>
            <button type="button" value="bol" onclick="getOperator('carp')">/</button>
            <button type="button" value="carp" onclick="getOperator('bol')">*</button>
            
        
        </div>
        
    
    
    
    </div>
    
    

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the addition works but How can I get second number from getValue(pal ) method ?

Comment: apply `num2` .you get the second value number.see with console.log of my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that when you press the `+` button, you don't know yet what the second number will be, since the user still has to input that. So doing this:

```
    if(val=="topla"){  
        memory=num1+num2;
    }
```

... is premature: `num2` is not yet known (0).

Instead, you should save the chosen operator in a variable, and then when the user presses `=`, you *will* have both numbers and the operator. At that moment you can perform the evaluation.

So use this as *getOperator*

```
var oper = ''; // new variable

function getOperator(val){
    document.getElementById("input").value="";
    if(val=="="){
        if(oper=="topla"){  
            memory=num1+num2;
        }
        // add other operators here ...
        //
        document.getElementById("input").value=memory;
    } else {
        oper = val; // save operator for later use...
    }
}
```

Note that you still have many challenges ahead:

- allow users to input numbers that have more than one digit
- perform multiple operations after each other
- make sure multiplication/division gets precedence over addition/subtraction

That is of course out of the scope of this question.